# Error acquiring token while using react app for azure

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory

this is my app.js

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import { PublicClientApplication, InteractionType } from "@azure/msal-browser";

    const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
    clientId: "f87c7548-4942-46cf-a69b-c0dccc5f5b1f",
    authority:
      "https://login.microsoftonline.com/63cdbcad-50c7-45d4-961c-b36bcfdab344",
    redirectUri: "http://localhost:3000/", // Set the correct redirect URL
   },
   };

    function App() {
   const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState("");
   const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);
   const pca = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
   useEffect(() => {
    const initializeMsal = async () => {
      await pca.initialize(); // Initialize MSAL instance
      setInitialized(true);
    };

    initializeMsal();
   }, []);

   const getAccessToken = async () => {
    if (!initialized) {
      console.log("MSAL not initialized yet");
      return;
    }

    try {
      const response = await pca.acquireTokenPopup({
        scopes: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"], // Replace with necessary scopes
        interactionType: InteractionType.Popup,
      });

      if (response.accessToken) {
        setAccessToken(response.accessToken);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error acquiring token:", error);
    }
    };

   useEffect(() => {
    if (initialized) {
      getAccessToken();
    }
    }, [initialized]);

    return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Access Token: {accessToken}</h1>
    </div>
    );
    }

    export default App;`
```

i am trying to get access token from azure but when i am running this it is giving error

Error acquiring token: BrowserAuthError: uninitialized_public_client_application: You must call and await the initialize function before attempting to call any other MSAL API.

i tried npm start after that i get this error

Error acquiring token: BrowserAuthError: uninitialized_public_client_application: You must call and await the initialize function before attempting to call any other MSAL API.

Comment: I have the same issue when switching to version 3.0.1

Comment: Will look into this tomorrow https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/msal-net-3.0.1 even though .net

Comment: So I see 3.0.2 was working but must have been dreaming cos it does not. Reverting back to "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.37.0"

Comment: Raised at https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/6375

Comment: The answer to this is as given below

Answer (score 4):

In the MSAL library for browser-based applications, there's no initialize method for PublicClientApplication. Hence, your call to await pca.initialize(); is likely causing an error. You don't need to manually initialize PublicClientApplication as it gets initialized when you instantiate it with the configuration.

Also you are essentially calling getAccessToken immediately after instantiation, without checking if MSAL is properly initialized. Given the absence of the initialize method in MSAL, the first useEffect isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

The below code does await pca.initialize() inside an async function inside useEffect , but ***initializeMsal() function call is called like a synchronous function , it's not waited for a result*** and I guess you didn't add that as it's inside useEffect .

```js
   useEffect(() => {
    const initializeMsal = async () => {
      await pca.initialize(); // Initialize MSAL instance
      setInitialized(true);
    };

    initializeMsal();
   }, []);
```

The following code similar to yours is working :

```js
export const callBackendApi: () => Promise<void> = async () => {
    const pca = new PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
    const init = await pca.initialize();    
    const accounts: AccountInfo[] = pca.getAllAccounts();
    if (accounts && accounts[0]) {
        const account: AccountInfo = accounts[0];
        if (account) {
            pca.setActiveAccount(account);
            acquireTokenAndCallApi(pca, account);
        }
    } else {
        const popupRequest: PopupRequest = {scopes:scopes};
        const res = await pca.acquireTokenPopup(popupRequest);
        if (res && res.accessToken && res.account) {
            pca.setActiveAccount(res.account);
            acquireTokenAndCallApi(pca, res.account);
        }
    }
}
```